# Long file path for excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2008, excel-2007

I have a problem while using excel application in vb.net.

I am trying something like this:-

```
 Dim lobjExcelApp As New Application

 Dim lstrSourceFilePath As String = "E:\VTL\VTL_Working\Source\Server Module                             Projects\Server Module VTL UnitTesting\TestResults\spfadmin_INSPEXEVTL2K8-1 2012-07-19 14_52_20\Out\..\..\..\..\..\Server Module Projects\Server Module VTL UnitTesting\VTL\Server\Unit Testing\Validation\TestFiles\01 - Tag-Anode Index.xlsx"


 Dim lobjExcelWorkbook As Workbook = lobjExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(lstrSourceFilePath)
```

The file path is of 248 characters.

Excel throws an error when i open the file.

This problem occurred on Windows Server 2008(64 bit) and Excel 2007 (32 bit)

Could someone help why the problem is caused?

Is there any workaround or solution for this?

Thanks

Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the *long* path. Take a look at blog-post by Jeff Atwood - [Filesystem Paths: How Long is Too Long?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/filesystem-paths-how-long-is-too-long.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. Strange thing is the long path i specified works on Windows 7 32 bit machine